# Use getDeclaredMethod using a function as a parameterType

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

I have a private method which header is:

```
private fun setNumericListener(editText: EditText, onValueChanged:(newValue: Double?) -> Unit)
```

I call this method in this way: `setNumericListener(amountEditText, this::onAmountChanged)`

I would like to use getDeclaredMethod from Class 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...) to get a reference to my private method `setNumericListener`. `getDeclaredMethod`receives an array of parameter types `Class<?>... parameterTypes` but I have no idea about how to set the parameter types array when my private method has a method reference as a parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function reference is resolved as being of type [`kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md).

This means you can use [`getDeclaredMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) to get a method reference by calling:

```
getDeclaredMethod("setNumericListener", EditText::class.java, Function1::class.java)
```

Here's a complete snippet:

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
    val method = Test::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("setNumericListener",
            EditText::class.java, Function1::class.java)

    println(method)
}

// Declarations
class Test {
    private fun setNumericListener(editText: EditText,
            onValueChanged: (d: Double?) -> Unit) {}
}

class EditText {}
```

Which prints:

```
private final void Test.setNumericListener(EditText,kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1)
```